# Why does Visual Studio report a lambda error in a working WebAPI code on .Net Core?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda, asp.net-core, resharper

I migrated an WebAPI from FullDotnet (4.6) to .Net Core 2.0 and I'm having this issue in my Data Layer using Dapper.

My code:

```
public List<Doctor> GetList()
{
    List<Doctor> ret;
    using (var db = GetMySqlConnection())
    {
        const string sql = @"SELECT D.Id, D.Bio, D.CRMState, D.CRMNumber,
        U.Id, U.Email, U.CreatedOn, U.LastLogon, U.Login, U.Name, U.Phone, U.Surname, U.Id, U.Birth, U.CPF,
        S.Id, S.Name
        from Doctor D
        inner join User U on U.Id = D.UserId
        inner join Speciality S on S.Id = D.IDEspeciality
        order by D.Id DESC";

        ret = db.Query<Doctor, User, Speciality, Doctor>(sql, (doctor, user, speciality) =>
        {
            doctor.User = user;
            doctor.Speciality = speciality;
            return doctor;
        }
        , splitOn: "Id, Id", commandType: CommandType.Text).ToList();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Strange Behavior:

[image: PrintScreen from code]

The solution **Builds and WORK**
The "error" who VisualStudio highlight is:

> Argument type 'lambda expression' is not assignable to parameter type
>   'System.Func`5'

I have another classes with the same behavior and same error, but, again, the code **compile and work,** but this "error highlight" is annoying!

*This highlight I don't have in my old solution running .NET Framework 4.6*

Usefull info:

- Class Library: .Net Standard 2.0
- Visual Studio 2017 v15.4.1
- Resharper 2017.2

Comment: You can try a few things: `clean` and `rebuild` the project, delete the `bin` and `obj` folders, restore `NuGet` packages..

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried again ( I tried the clean before , something VS cause this) , Clean, Rebuild, Deleted bin, Clean, Build, Rebuild, nothing! same behavior! The solution and projects I created yesterdar from Zero, not migrated anything , everything new and clean, installed the nugets and copied my code, I will try to run in another machine just to see if there is something weird with my VS

Comment: Try to specify the parameter type in your lambda (Doctor doctor, User user, Speciality Speciality) => (...)

Comment: @Seb Just tried, nothing :( same error.

Comment: Just to note, in another computer I have the same issue :(, I Also tried create a new project and use the same class and the error persists.. :(

Comment: Are you using ReSharper by any chance? If yes, which version?

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi yes, 2017.2, Now I'm finishing to create a new VM fully clean only with VS 2017 to test my solution. I Suspect of Resharper causing this maybe?

Comment: That's my suspicion. Go to Tools/Options.../Resharper node in the tree and try disabling ReSharper, by clicking "Suspend Now"

Comment: Omg, you're right mate, It's a resharper issue. Now i'll try to figure out to fix this with Resharper. to ignore this.

Comment: If you can, try the latest version (2017.2.2), if the issue still persists, then open an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi I will, but now look, I disabled as you asked, and enabled again... restarted visual studio... no error anymore :O

Comment: But I will update to test 2017.2.2.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi Updated to 2017.2.2, opened 2 projects here, no errors anymore, well, to solve it just disable and enable resharper again, looks like some kind of cache or refresh was necessary to Resharper. Please post a answer with the solution you provided to give you the Credits :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as we figured it out in the comments, the issue was caused by ReSharper (2017.2).

Some additional steps you can take when suspecting that ReSharper is acting up.

**Suspend/resume ReSharper**

Just to confirm that ReSharper is causing issues, you can suspend it using:

`Tools/Options.../Resharper node/Suspend now`

In this case doing a suspend/resume cycle was enough and solved the issue.

**Clearing ReSharper cache** ([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configuring_Caches_Location.html#cleanup))

> Broken caches affect ReSharper behavior. For example, ReSharper can
>   stop resolving symbols or some navigation commands can be unavailable.
>   If you notice such strange behavior, clearing caches for the current
>   solution could help in most cases.
>
> To clear caches for the current solution
>
> 1. Open the solution with supposedly broken caches in Visual Studio.
> 2. Open the Environment | General page of ReSharper options.
> 3. Click Clear caches. Note that the caches will be only cleaned in the currently selected cache location.
> 4. Reopen your solution for the changes to take effect.
>
> ReSharper also cleans up solution caches automatically if a
>   specific solution was not open for more than 30 days.

**What if the above doesn't work?**

If you confirmed that it's a ReSharper issue, then you should first try and update to the latest version of ReSharper and try to reproduce your problem.

If the issue still persists, then you should head to the [JetBrains bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) and file an issue after confirming that it's not an already reported bug.

Comment: Cheers my friend !